# Loop control variable, %s, has file scope

Tags: c, global-variables

I have been working on resolving a QAC warning and I am not able to resolve this particular warning which says  "Loop control variable, %s, has file scope" even though it seems to be a global variable. What am I doing wrong?

In file1.h

```
extern int variable;
```

In file1.c

```
#include "file1.h"
void func1(void)

{
  variable = 1
}

void func2(void)
{
 while(variable==1)// WARNING : Loop control variable, %s, has file scope
   {
     Do something
   }
}
```

file2.c

```
#include file1.h

if(variable==1)
{
   do something
}
```

Comment: What is `QAC` ?

Comment: the code looks fine (ignoring the global variable...) What is "QAC"?

Comment: Shouldn't the `if(variable==1) {...}` in file2.c be in a function? And `file1.h` be between double-quotes?

Comment: post some code that will actually compile. Tell us what compiler you are using

Comment: "*even though it seems to be a global variable*" - that's exactly what it's complaining about.

Comment: I am using a trace 32 compiler. The code does compile but I am trying to resolve this warning

Comment: "QA·C detects and reports on dataﬂow problems, software defects,language implementation errors, inconsistencies, dangerous usage and coding standard violations quickly and efﬁciently via a C language proprietary parser, integrated with a sophisticated dataflow engine . Various reports on detected defects as well as metric calculations can be created, and personalized. Compliance mdoules provide support for MISRA C:1998, MISRA C:2004, and MISRA C:2012."

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the definition (`int variable;`), with or without initialisation, is somewhere in file1.c, but that assumption is probably not even necessary.

QAC in this case does not mean to complain "is file scope, should be global".
It is more like "is file scope, should be function-local".
QAC is a fan of minimising variable scopes, especially loop control variables.

Comment: "I assume that the definition (int variable;), with or without initialisation, is somewhere in file1.c, but that assumption is probably not even necessary." You are right it is in file1.c

Comment: Is it possible to make this function scope when the used cases are in different functions?

Comment: @AryanVarma: is there a reason you're not passing the value as an argument to the different functions?

Comment: @John Bode, funny that I am trying exactly this as I type. The only reason why I did not try this yet was because this function is a part of a much larger code and changing it in one place would lead to changing it in multiple places.

Comment: The while loop only makes sense if the variable can change during the function execution. In order to notice that, the parameter needs to be a pointer to the variable, not a call-by-value. The function with the `if` might work with a simple parameter. Please make a [mcve] with all relevant parts.